# Using TFS 2015 Build to build projects in TFS 2013

Tags: tfs, build, tfs-2015

We currently use TFS 2013.

I'd like to do a POC where I can create some build definitions in TFS 2015 where it would get the source from our existing TFS 2013 server.  Once the boss sees how much easier it is to manage our builds from TFS 2015, I'm sure he'll give us the go-ahead with upgrading the existing TFS 2013 to TFS 2015.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a PowerShell script or some batch files to leverage `tf.exe` in order to map a workspace / clone a repo (depending on whether you're using TFVC or Git) as part of a build. Or just put the tip of your source code into the "demo" environment and build from there. The latter option is going to be much faster.

Comment: That sounds very sensible.  It's a POC after all, so can just put a few projects into a clean TFS 2015 installation to demo the new build technology.  Cheers.